# PHP performance optimization foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am not sure if it would be helpful to post the full code here or to post an example, since it is rather large script, I will post what I think is the necessary components.

I am calling a txt file and counting each new row as an array which I put into an foreach loop

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('show_errors', 1);
$file = "file.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while (($name = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $row = explode ("<br>", $name );
    foreach ($row as $fname) {
        /* ... some code ... */
    }
}
```

inside the foreach loop I have about 4 Curl operations followed by some `phpexcel functions` 
and an else statement which contains 4 more curl operations (identical),

What should I do to optimize performance, I was thinking of either running a) the `foreach` statement as shown above in an seperate file and just using `include()` for the rest, or using functions for the curl operations, but I am interested if anyone else had an idea on how to improve performance.

Comment: Moving this code to a separate function or file doesn't change anything. It's like moving your wallet from one pocket to another and expect to get more money after that in it.

Comment: not using a flat file as a db, would be a start

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching multiple resources with cURL, if you know what they are ahead of time (and don't have to download them serially) why not use multi-cURL?  You can fetch all the resources simultaneously.  You can either [use it directly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), or use one of the many classes that make it easier.  https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl